# form is not submitted and I can't get post data after form submit

Tags: php, forms, symfony, formbuilder

I'm trying to run a simple form, but it doesn't work and there aren't error message

**UserType.php**

```
<?php

namespace BISSAP\ForumBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
class UserType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
    * @var Router
    */
    private $router;

    public function __construct(Router $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router; 
    }


     /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
            $builder
                    ->add('name', 'text', array('required' => false))
                    ->setAction($this->router->generate('bissap_forum_test'))
                    ->setMethod('POST')
                    ->add('Envoyer', 'submit', array(
                        'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'btn right-flt'
                        )));


    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'BISSAP\UserBundle\Entity\Usertmp'
        ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver) 
    { 
        $resolver->setDefaults(array( 'data_class' => $this->class, 'intention' => 'Registration', 'validation_groups' => array('Registration'))); 
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'userType';
        // return 'bissap_forumbundle_user';
    }
}
```

**TController.php**

```
<?php

namespace BISSAP\ForumBundle\Controller;

use Doctrine\Common\DataFixtures\FixtureInterface;
use Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager;
use BISSAP\ForumBundle\Form\UserType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use BISSAP\UserBundle\Entity\Usertmp;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

class TController extends Controller
{

  public function indexAction(Request $request)
  {
    //$entity = new Usertmp();
    $form = $this->createForm('userType', $entity, array('validation_groups' => 'Registration'));

    $data_post = $request->request->get('name');

    if ($form->isValid())
    {
        return $this->redirectToRoute('bissap_forum_index');
    }

    return $this->render('BISSAPForumBundle:T:index.html.twig', array('form'=> $form->createView(), 'errors_tmp' => $this->getErrorMessages($form), 'data_post' => $data_post2));
  }

  private function getErrorMessages(\Symfony\Component\Form\Form $form) 
  {      
        $errors = array();
        foreach ($form->getErrors(true, false) as $error) {

        $errors[] = $error->current()->getMessage();
        }

        return $errors;
    }

}
?>
```

In this Controller, I try to get POST data and display it in template **(index.html.twig)** with :

```
$data_post = $request->request->get('name');
```

but `$data_post` is empty

**UserTmp.php**

```
<?php

namespace BISSAP\UserBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * BISSAP\UserBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="BISSAP\UserBundle\Entity\UserRepository")
 */
class Usertmp 
{

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
 *
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Please enter your name.", groups={"Registration", "Profile"})
 * @Assert\Length(
 *     min=3,
 *     max=255,
 *     minMessage="The name is too short.",
 *     maxMessage="The name is too long.",
 *     groups={"Registration", "Profile"}
 * )
 */
private $name;



/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Usertmp
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}
}
```

**service.yml**

```
   bissap_forum.test_form:
        class: BISSAP\ForumBundle\Form\UserType
        arguments: ['@router']
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: userType }
```

**index.html.twig**

```
{{form( form )}}
{% for error in errors_tmp %}
    <div>error : {{ error }}</div>
{% endfor %} 

<div>data_post : {{ data_post }}</div>
```

**Form HTML generated with `$form->createView()` :**

```
<form name="userType" method="post" action="/bodykoncept/web/app_dev.php/forum/test">
    <div id="userType"><div>
        <label for="userType_name">Name</label>
        <input id="userType_name" name="userType[name]" type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" id="userType_Envoyer" name="userType[Envoyer]" class="btn right-flt">Envoyer</button>
</div>
        <input id="userType__token" name="userType[_token]" value="ldFnSgioYkQEI6WOzqFJterUSrBoEagSct2m5p2oQmY" type="hidden">
    </div>
</form>

<div>data_post : </div>
```

`<input id="userType_name" name="userType[name]" type="text">` :

Name Input = **userType[name]** 
maybe is this for reason that

`$data_post = $request->request->get('name');` in **TController.php** is empty.

This form is not submited, `$this->submitted is false` in `vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form.php`

Comment: You need $form->handleRequest($request) before the submitted stuff works.  And yes, your get('name') won't work because the element name is userType[name]. Plenty of examples in the docs.

Comment: `$form->handeRequest($request)` => ok.  And i changed `$request->request->get('name')` by `$this->getRequest()->get('userType')['name'];`